# Remove headers from CSV export in SSRS/VS Designer

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, export-to-csv, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm not sure where to ask this question.  I've been all over the web looking for an answer.

I'm trying to export a report as pipe delimited and without headers.  I've found several discussions about how to change the config file on the server.  But I'm not there yet.

I'm on my local machine.  I'm running VS 2015 (14.0.25431.01 Update 3).  It has SQL Server Reporting Services (14.0.806.134) installed.  I can create a report as a Report Server Project.  When I preview the report then go to export (not deploy) it as CSV the resulting file has headers.  I need to remove those headers.

Some say I need to edit the config file rsreportserver.config
For example, "Open rsreportserver.config file under C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server{INSTANCE}\Reporting Services\ReportServer in reporting server."

Why would it be under SQL Server folder?  Do I need a SQL Server installed/running to make VS work?  I don't think so.  What if I have more than one server installed locally?  Nothing in my VS setup indicates what server to use.  So how would VS ever find this file?

I did find rsreportserver.config in 2 places under a local instance of SQL Server 2016 Developer.  Changing these did not affect the VS output.  I didn't expect it to since VS knows nothing about any servers until I make some explicit connection.

My question is how can I configure VS Reporting Services Report Designer to create a pipe delimited, no header export?

Comment: The guides you are looking at are for SQL Server, not for SSDT.. I'm not sure you can add custom export types to SSDT. It's a development environment, it's not to be used as a replacement for doing production functions. That's for SSRS is for.

Comment: I search the web for VISUAL STUDIO but all I get are SERVER links.  That's my problem.  I realize SSDT is a development environment.  But, isn't it supposed to be WYSIWYG?  What you see is what you get?  How can I format my layout if I can't see the final result?  It's a pain to deploy every time I make a change just to see what I have and that I didn't break something.

Comment: SSDT includes the export function.  Therefore the designers must have thought this an important feature.

Comment: They have, indeed, included an export function, yes, but like I said it's a development environment and it's not SSRS; you can't test SSRS configuration settings in SSDT (which is what you're trying to do). When using a custom export type though, you don't need to keep deploying your report. You need to simply edit the config file (make sure you make a back up!), and then restart the SSRS service. When you export from SSRS next, the new option'll be there. If it doesn't work (as expected), amend the config file, restart the service and export again. No need to go through redeployment at all.

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  And it appears MS has hardcoded the functionality in the design environment, so I'm SOL here.  But I reject the logic.  Why have a development environment if I can't test the design?  That's like having a word processor, but you can't read the document until you publish it.

Comment: Oops, hit return to soon.  As I think about this, I realize this IS SSRS.  That's the part that works.  In VS it looks just like it does when deployed to SSRS Server.  It's the export function that is outside of VS/SSRS.

Comment: How do I flag this as answered?  It's not the answer I was hoping for.  But I think it is the answer.

Comment: Without an answer to the post, you can't (as it's answered within the comments, as it was more a discussion than anything).. :)